# no implicit conversion of nil into String in spec

Tags: ruby

When I run this Ruby code I get error:

```
require "rails"
let(:xml_file) { File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'fixtures', 'xml', 'sale.xml') }
```

Result:

Failure/Error: let(:xml_file) { File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'fixtures', 'xml', 'sale.xml') }

```
 TypeError:
   no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

Do you know that is the cause of this issue and how I can fix it?
The xml file exists on the specified location.

Comment: are you sure `Rails` and `Rails.root` are defined at that point?

Comment: Do you run this in a rails app?

Answer (score 1):

`Rails.root` returns `nil` when there is no project. Make sure you initialize the project in your current workspace.

See http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails.html#method-c-root